# Arreglo de los nombres de usuarios ordenados por el id [ JS ]

Tags: javascript, array, ordenar

Necesito crear un arreglo con los nombres de los usuarios pero ordenado por sus ids.
Lo que hice fue aislar en un nuevo arreglo con un map a los nombres y ids, y luego trate de usar sort(function(a,b)) pero no me funciona.

```js
const users = [
    { dni: '86620855', id: 4,  nombres: 'Pedro Aguirre'},
    { dni: '7317855K', id: 1,  nombres: 'Juan Carlos'},
    { dni: '73826497', id: 6,  nombres: 'Esteban Herrera'},
    { dni: '88587715', id: 3,  nombres: 'Ricardo Lucas'},
    { dni: '94020190', id: 5,  nombres: 'Mauricio Hernandez'},
    { dni: '99804238', id: 2,  nombres: 'Silena Roz' }
  ]


const arreglo2= users.map(item => (
  {id: item.id, nombres: item.nombres}
))

const arreglotodo= arreglo2.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.nombres -b.nombres
})

console.log(arreglotodo)
```

Ya no se me ocurre como hacerlo. Existe alguna manera sencilla de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea la tienes muy clara, sin embargo no entiendo el porqué haces `sort` usando el campo nombre, si lo que quieres hacer es ordenar por `id`: ***Necesito crear un arreglo con los nombres de los usuarios pero ordenado por sus ids.***

Lo que debes hacer es usar el campo `id` en la función de comparación.

Por ejemplo, esto ordena la lista `users` de forma ascendente mediante el campo `id`:

```js
const users = [
  { dni: '86620855', id: 4,  nombres: 'Pedro Aguirre'},
  { dni: '7317855K', id: 1,  nombres: 'Juan Carlos'},
  { dni: '73826497', id: 6,  nombres: 'Esteban Herrera'},
  { dni: '88587715', id: 3,  nombres: 'Ricardo Lucas'},
  { dni: '94020190', id: 5,  nombres: 'Mauricio Hernandez'},
  { dni: '99804238', id: 2,  nombres: 'Silena Roz' }
];

users.sort((a, b) => {return a.id - b.id});

console.log(users);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.